# Error 1 'KortNummer' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'

Tags: c#, random, console-application

Im trying to get a random number by calling a method (FåKortNummer) in a class but i get an error like in the title that says that my System.Random is a variable but is treated like a method how do i fix this problem

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Kortspil
    {
        public class Krig
        {
            public byte FåKortNummer()
            {
                System.Random KortNummer = new System.Random();
                byte kort = KortNummer(1, 11);
                return kort;
            }
        }
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                byte kort = Krig.FåKortNummer();
                Console.WriteLine(kort.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `KortNummer` is an instane of `Random` class. It is not a method. What do you try to do with `KortNummer(1, 11)` exactly?

Comment: When someone uses æøå in anything other than string literals, a bunny dies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you put a pair of parentheses after an expression, you are telling the C# compiler that you would like it to invoke a method. Hence the "used like a 'method'" error.

If you are looking to obtain a random `byte`, you can do it like this:

```
byte kort = (byte)KortNummer.Next(1, 11);
```

This calls the [`Next` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the `KortNummer` variable, producing a number from 1 to 11.

Answer (score 1):

You are not properly calling the `Random` class methods to generate Random Numbers.

You need to Call `Next()` method of Random class to generate Random number

**From MSDN:** [`Random.Next()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Returns a random integer that is within a specified range.

this method returns the `int` value and you need to cast it back to `byte` as integer  can not be implicitly converted to `byte`.

Try This:

```
byte kort = Convert.ToByte(KortNummer.Next(1, 11));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Next` method to get a `Random` number.`KortNumber` is the name of the `Random` instance.You can't use it like that:

```
byte kort = (byte)KortNummer.Next(1, 11);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it static so you don't have to instantiate the `Krig` class, second, make the `System.Random` a static variable, this way when you call the method in a loop you won't get the same number everytime. Third, you need to call the `random.Next` Method.

```
private static System.Random KortNummer = new System.Random();
public static byte FåKortNummer()
{
    byte kort = (byte)KortNummer.Next(1, 11);
    return kort;
}
```